# How to update json object with dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

The goal is to update a json object that contains a particular key

The json file looks like:

```
{
 "collection": [
{"name": "name1", "phone": "10203040"}, 
{"name": "name2", "phone": "20304050", "corporateIdentificationNumber": "1234"}, 
{"name": "name3", "phone": "30405060", "corporateIdentificationNumber": "5678"}
]}
```

if a json object contains the key 'corporateIdentificationNumber', then iterate through a dictonary and update 'name' and 'corporateIdentificationNumber' from dictionary. Dictionary looks like this:

```
dict = {"westbuilt": "4232", "Northbound": "5556"}
```

In other words that means that i need to update the json object with a dictionary, and whenever i am updating a json object, it should select key/value pair from dictionary, and then iterate to next key/value for next json object containing 'corporateIdentificationNumber'

Code:

```
r = requests.get(url="*URL*")
file = r.json()

for i in file['collection']:
    if 'corporateIdentificationNumber' in i:
        --- select next iterated key/value from dict---
        --- update json object ---
```

result should look like:

```
   {
 "collection": [
{"name": "name1", "phone": "10203040"}, 
{"name": "westbuilt", "phone": "20304050", "corporateIdentificationNumber": "4232"}, 
{"name": "Northbound", "phone": "30405060", "corporateIdentificationNumber": "5556"}
]}
```

Comment: What should the resulting json file look like?

Comment: @quamrana HI, thank you for your time. I have just updated my question with how i expect the result to look like

Comment: So, you are relying on the order of items in `dict` (badly named btw) to overwrite values in  the `collection` list?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Not sure, if this is the correct way of doing it. i am in deep water right now

Comment: JSON object is a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use an iterator to the items:

```py
updates = {"westbuilt": "4232", "Northbound": "5556"}

r = requests.get(url="*URL*")
file = r.json()

items = iter(updates.items())
try:
    for i in file['collection']:
        if 'corporateIdentificationNumber' in i:
            d = next(items)
            i['name'] = d[0]
            i["corporateIdentificationNumber"] = d[1]
except StopIteration:
    pass

print(file)
```

Comment: You are a life saver. This is works and is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
json_object["corporateIdentificationNumber"] = "updated value"
file = open("your_json_file.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, file)
file.close()
```

Comment: Code only answers are not in general helpful.

Comment: The required pieces of information are integrated into the code. "updated value" and "your_json_file".